# Receive and send a javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery

**It is solved now**

The problem was that I thought `getParameterByName()` was a defined function, but it is not the case so you need to add this function:

```
function getParameterByName( name ){
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

I hope it helps newbies like me...

---

I need to receive a variable from the url and, if the user clicks on a button, then send it to another page. To do so, I have got the following code:

**html**

```
<input type="button" id="login-button" onclick="factura_si()" value="Yes"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function factura_si() {
var n = getParameterByName('n');
var string_url = "https://www.webpage.php?" + "&n=" + n;
window.location = string_url;
}
```

When I use this script, the button does not redirect to the location. Is there something wrong with it?

The function

```
factura_si() { 
  var n = getParameterByName('n'); 
  document.write(n); 
}
```

returns nothing... But if I change the parameter 'n' by a random chain of letters 'grniegor', the button shows the chain.

Comment: What is returned by `getParameterByName`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code `function factura_si() {
    var n = getParameterByName('n');
    document.write(n);
}` returns nothing... But if I change the parameter 'n' by a random chain of letters 'grniegor', the button shows the chain.

Comment: There you have your problem. if getParameterByName returns nothing it means that "n" is undefined, so when you try to add "undefined" to the url string it fails and the whole script stops working. "n" needs to be something or you have to check if it exists first and only add it to the url if it does.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The parameter 'n' comes inside the url. I want to get this parameter and send it to the new page.

Comment: Oh you want to GET it from the url and then send it where? the same url?

Comment: I want to get it from something like `https://...process.php?n=$n` and send it something like `https://...factura.php?n=$n`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `window.location.href`:

```js
window.location.href = string_url;
```

`window.location` is an object describing the location of the current page. Setting it's `href` property causes the page to jump to the new url.

Comment: You can skip `window` part and it will work the same.

Comment: Yes but here it's clear that `location` is a global variable and not defined in some function.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not working with the `.href`. I will update the original post with new info

Answer (score -1):

I probe this code and it works, if this does not work for you. 
You can check the development tools, maybe the problem is elsewhere.

```
<input type="button" id="login-button" onclick="factura_si()" value="Yes"/>
```

the Js functions

```
function factura_si() {
    var n = getParameterByName('n');
    var string_url = "https://www.webpage.php?" + "&n=" + n;
    window.location = string_url;
}

function getParameterByName(n) {
    //call server or somthing...
  return "somo_path";
}
```